# Changes made in text file (programatically ) are not reflected back

Tags: c#-3.0

I have following code. On making changes in the text file when I open the file I can't see any change in fact the text of text file is removed.

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string content;

        string newword = "Tanu";
        string oldword = "Sunrise";
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
           new System.IO.StreamReader(txtFilePath.Text);

        while ((content = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (content == "Project name = Sunrise ")
            {
                string newtxt = Regex.Replace(content, oldword, newword);
                content = content.Replace(content, newtxt);
            }
           // counter++;
        }

        file.Close();

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(txtFilePath.Text))
        {
            writer.Write(content);

            writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is in your while loop.

`while ((content = file.ReadLine()) != null)`

after replacing content with newtxt while is executing again and is trying to read next line in file which is setting content to null and so when you come out of while loop your content is null.

try reading file content into a different variable or use say newtxt itself to write to file.